# Detaching interrupts

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, interrupt

I am using the following code to enable an interrupt for a pin:

```
*digitalPinToPCMSK(pin) |= bit (digitalPinToPCMSKbit(pin));  // enable pin
PCIFR  |= bit (digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin)); // clear any outstanding interrupt
PCICR  |= bit (digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin)); // enable interrupt for the group
```

But I can't disable it. I am trying with this code:

```
if (*digitalPinToPCMSK(pin) == 0)
*digitalPinToPCICR(pin) &= ~(1<<digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin));
```

but it isn't working.

Comment: What pin is it? Why not use `attachInterrupt` and `detachInterrupt`?

Comment: The code is inside a function. attachInterrupt only works for two pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mean:

```
  PCICR  &= ~bit (digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin));
```